# Approximating the integral of a large product

Tags: integration, approximation

I would like to approximate the following integral of a product:

$$
I = \int dz\, f(z)\prod_{i=1}^n\left(1 - \rho_i(z)\right)
$$

The functions $f$ and $\rho_i$ are differentiable for all $i$, $\rho_i(z) \ll 1$ for all $z$ and $i$, and $\int dz\, f(z)=1$.

My initial hunch was to exchange the order of the integral and the product because the cross-terms of $\rho$s are likely small. Then

$$
I \approx \prod_{i=1}^n\left(1- \int dz\, f(z)\rho_i(z)\right).
$$

Are there better and/or more well-motivated approximations?

Comment: If $n$ is very large, you can just find the closed form for the intinite product for $n \to \infty$. It would help to know the explicit form for $\rho_i (z)$